# Why does Zenitsu hate Inosuke? Do they ever become friends?

Tags: demon-slayer

In *Demon Slayer*, Zenitsu seems to hate Inosuke.

First of all, I am aware that Zenitsu and Inosuke started off on the wrong foot. Inosuke and Tanjiro did not start off on good terms either but, Tanjiro and Inosuke made friends.

When watching it for the first time, I thought that Zenitsu and Inosuke had made friends with each other or would eventually. However, Zenitsu hates Inosuke and is always mean to him by insulting him. While the insults could just be from annoyance, there's also the fact that Zenitsu does not care about Inosuke's well-being.

Why does he hate him so much? Do they ever become friends?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Just a friendly tip, if you're logged in with your account, then you can edit and improve your own post freely. Also, feel free to take a quick [tour] to understand how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to the wikia it's because they have contrasting personalities.

> Zenitsu and Inosuke usually do not get along despite being on the same
> team, mainly due to their extremely low opinions of each other and
> their wildly contrasting personalities. Inosuke sees Zenitsu as
> annoying, loud, weak (initially), and a crybaby; while Zenitsu sees
> Inosuke as a violent moron who's only interested in fighting. However,
> in dire situations, they can cooperate well. Inosuke shows a level of
> admiration for Zenitsu's abilities while asleep, saying he should
> sleep forever after seeing how cool he fights for the first time.

[Zenitsu relationships](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Zenitsu_Agatsuma/Relationships#Inosuke_Hashibira)

I would add that they didnt start well because Inosuke wanted to kill Nezuko when they first met, and Zenitsu loves Nezuko.